# (Material UI v5) Global style overrides

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

There is the [Global style overrides](https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#global-style-overrides) example in MUI:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        // Name of the slot
        root: {
          // Some CSS
          fontSize: '1rem',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I have the [InputLabel](https://mui.com/api/input-label/#main-content) component in my code and I want to change its on **focused** label text **color**. [By default it's #1976d2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjU3R.png)

The responsible CSS rule is:

```
.css-1g2sqwz-MuiFormLabel-root-MuiInputLabel-root.Mui-focused {
    color: #1976d2;
}
```

How can I override it by using that Global style overrides example above?

How can I change the on focused label text color?

The code part below isn't working:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiInputLabel: {
      styleOverrides: {
        focused: {
          color: 'red',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Below is the correct way to target the "focused" state. Overriding the focused styles requires a CSS class combined with `Mui-focused` in order to get sufficient [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to override the default styles.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiInputLabel: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "&.Mui-focused": {
            color: "red"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit InputLabel focused]

Comment: Doesn’t this make any slots other than “root” redundant? Seems odd why they went to all the trouble and specificity overrides everything?